# How to Paginate Related Table From a Single Request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest, laravel-8

I'm new to Laravel and PHP in general and was wondering how I could paginate the tweets data in my example below:

```php
Route::get("/users/{user}", function (User $user) {
    return $user->only(
        "id",
        "name",
        "username",
        "avatar",
        "profile",
        "location",
        "link",
        "linkText",
        "created_at",
        "tweets"
    );
});
```

[image]

The `tweets` table is related to `user` so I could say `$user->tweets()->paginate(10);` but how can I return that along with my `only()` method? also, is there a way for me to return multiple stuffs and can still access them on my frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look into [API resources](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources).

The `only()` function is to be used *after* the query has completed, because it strips data from your model even though you have retrieved them from the database. Your call to `tweets()` makes it a query object (without the `()` it would resolve to a collection object), so you are still able to chain query functions.

I suppose you could also call `$user->tweets()->select(['id', 'user_id', 'body', ...])->paginate(10);` to only select the columns you need.

Comment: I think I've done it [screenshot1](https://imgur.com/a/YIe4ko0) but can you confirm if everything I did was all right? [screenshot2](https://imgur.com/a/3jDUOoo) [screenshot3](https://imgur.com/a/6TtElnC) [screenshot4](https://imgur.com/a/IwThAfJ)

Comment: yes looks good. I'd define the routes properly in a separate routes file though and link them to controllers. It depends a bit on the size of your app though

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more customizable pagination, you can try using `limit` and `offset` or `skip` and `take` then look into [API Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-resources) as suggested above

Comment: I think I've done it [screenshot1](https://imgur.com/a/YIe4ko0) but can you confirm if everything I did was all right? [screenshot2](https://imgur.com/a/3jDUOoo) [screenshot3](https://imgur.com/a/6TtElnC) [screenshot4](https://imgur.com/a/IwThAfJ)